# How do i get the graph to draw a line for constant 0 values using amcharts?

Tags: amcharts

I'm showing network throughput and disk io's in a graph.
But when there is no activity. 0 get's reported. 
The balloon shows me 0 but the line is not being drawn.
it looks like the grid is on top but if I turn the grid off the line still isn't there.

if I make line-thickness 2, I can see it but then the line changes thickness between 0 value and non 0 value. from 1px  to 2 px.

i can't find anything in the documentation about this.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a limitation with the library as it doesn't draw lines outside of the plot area so the line will be clipped at the edges as you've noticed. Setting the lineThickness to a larger number like you already did along with setting the valueAxis' [`zeroGridAlpha`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#zeroGridAlpha) property to zero will improve it slightly, but your best bet is setting a small negative [`minimum`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minimum) in your valueAxis so that the zero line is clearly visible. You can combine this with setting [`showFirstLabel`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#showFirstLabel) to false to hide the first negative value in your axis.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/df2d96e44e9a842fe5b7c634c55b8369?editors=0010)